# Mysql how to get First Monday of given year and Month

Tags: mysql

How to get the first monday of given year month.

```
SET @YearMonth:= '201304';

Result:
2013-04-01 (For April)
2013-11-04 (For November)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I  have using teh week & weekofyear function.. but can't get the correct answer.

Comment: What @Brewal asked is what query did you try. You should display the query you tried.

Comment: Gabriel L , it is not mandatory to display query... right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
SET @firstday = '2013-04-01';

SELECT ADDDATE( @firstday , MOD((9-DAYOFWEEK(@firstday)),7)) as first_monday;
```

The param @firstday is the first day of the month you want to search.
Note that sunday is the first day of a week, monday is the second day.

Comment: The answer was helpful. I would like to know the logic of adding 9 in MOD.