# How to set week range of month start from Monday to Sunday?

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is my query

```
SELECT 
week,
weekname,
DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL (week-1) WEEK) as 'Week Start',
IF(DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL ((week-1)*7+6) DAY) > eom, 
      eom,
      DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL ((week-1)*7+6) DAY)) as 'Week End'
FROM (
   SELECT
    date,
    FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(date) - 1) / 7 +1) AS week,
    CONCAT('Week ',FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(date) - 1) / 7) +1) AS weekname,
    DATE_ADD(date,interval -DAY(date)+1 DAY) AS firstOfMonth,
    LAST_DAY(date) as 'eom'
FROM attendance
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%Y')='10/2022' 
GROUP BY week
) a;
```

Below its output from above, but I need the week start is 03-09 oct as 1st week, 10 - 16, 17 - 23, 24 - 30, 31 oct - 06 nov 2022.

[image]

Comment: Check this to get first monday in month https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002112/mysql-how-to-get-first-monday-of-given-year-and-month

Comment: I'm a little confused by the published table , is that your desired outcome if not add it.

Comment: its not the output I wanted. I need the week start is 03 -09 oct as 1st week, 10 - 16, 17 - 23, 24 - 30, 31 oct - 06 nov. Is it possible to get week of month?? @P.Salmon

Comment: Sure is , did you read and digest the link?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, I read the link from you.. But, I still not understand how to in format in the table attached